# Angular- Pass value to function from another function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular Typescript file, I have 2 functions `data` and `lists`. I am trying to pass variable `windows` from function data to function lists.

I am getting `Cannot find name 'back'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.lists'?ts(2663)`  error when trying to call function lists

**UPDATE**

If I use `this.list`, When I `console.log(windows)`, it gives `undefined`

```
data(less: Mark, quick: HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
  const { a,b,c } = less;
  const windows = quick.innerText;
  lists(windows);     ------>>>>> Cannot find name 'lists'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.lists'

  this.value.newLevel({a, b, c windows}).subscribe(data => {
    this.processView(data);
  })
}

lists(windows){
 console.log(windows) ---> If I use this.lists the value is undefined
}
```

Comment: *Did* you mean `this.lists`? What happens if you try that?

Comment: @luk2302 If I use `this.list`, When I `console.log(windows)`, it gives `undefined`

Comment: @TejasMehta When you are using `this.lists` you are getting `undefined` because `quick.innerText` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

List is in the same class, so you are trying to access a function inside an object. Instead of calling list, you have to call this.list

Comment: If I use `this.list`, When I `console.log(windows)`, it gives `undefined`

Comment: are you sure that `quick.innerText`  is not undefined? Try to console.log quick and then see if this object has innerText as a property

Answer (score 1):

```
//Here is your solution             
data(less: Mark, quick: HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
const { a,b,c } = less;
const windows = quick.innerText;
this.lists(windows);

this.value.newLevel({a, b, c windows}).subscribe(data => {
  this.processView(data);
})
}
lists(windows){}
```

Comment: If I use `this.list`, When I `console.log(windows)`, it gives `undefined`

Comment: use another naming convention instead using windows.